# get value from XML in vbnet

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm new in web service app using vbnet. the value return from service is in XML format.

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table> 
    <Symbol>Fe</Symbol>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

How can I retrieve the value without writing it into text file. I know there's a namespace SYSTEM.XML but I'm not familiar with its classes :(

Comment: have you tried to read up on the subject? Is the problem with reading the xml or is your problem with storing it in a file? If it is the latter you might want to write it to a MemoryStream?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's assume that your web service call gives you that XML in a string.

```
Dim MyXml as String = YourWebService.GetXml()
```

If you want to get the value of the "Symbol" tag, you could do this...

```
Dim MyDoc as New System.Xml.XmlDocument
MyDoc.LoadXml(MyXml)
dim SymbolText as String = MyDoc.SelectSingleNode("//NewDataSet/Table/Symbol").InnerText
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dim xmlstr As String = "<NewDataSet>
  <Table> 
    <Symbol>Fe</Symbol>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>"
        Dim doc As XElement = XElement.Parse(xmlstr)

        For Each val As XElement In doc.Descendants("Table")

            If val.HasElements Then
                Dim Symbol As String = val.Element("Symbol").Value
            End If
        Next
```