# update a specific value of xml with c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have been working with xml update and insert in c# but cannot implement update specific value. Below is my xml data:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Invoice xmlns='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2' xmlns:cac='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2' xmlns:cbc='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2' xmlns:ext='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2'>
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <ext:ExtensionContent>
                <!-- Please note that the signature values are sample values only -->
                <sig:UBLDocumentSignatures xmlns:sig='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2' xmlns:sac='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2' xmlns:sbc='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2'>
                    <sac:SignatureInformation>
                        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#' Id='signature'>
                            <ds:SignedInfo>
                                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11'/>
                                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256'/>
                                <ds:Reference Id='invoiceSignedData' URI=''>
                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256'/>
                                    <ds:DigestValue>WC7e+bBQQok9FOrS2y+BAYtnW9B5fvxtDXgJU6vhx5M=</ds:DigestValue>
                                </ds:Reference>
                                <ds:Reference Type='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties' URI='#xadesSignedProperties'>
                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256'/>
                                    <ds:DigestValue>ZjU2ZjM4YTExODRmNzE0ZjIxODA4MDYxYjhiMzdmM2JlMTJiNWQ0N2E2YjhjNzQwMjg2NDBkMzJlM2MxNjM2Nw==</ds:DigestValue>
                                </ds:Reference>
                            </ds:SignedInfo>
                            <ds:SignatureValue>MEUCIQCCGL7AJacVObs7luFYTbsqKr9qLZX+LYjZivOjDNnaYgIgT0SrZZKk3L8fzV8/J7h9p7wH0BoqplW0RBcWOVNeW0w=</ds:SignatureValue>
                            <ds:KeyInfo>
                                <ds:X509Data>
                                    <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                                </ds:X509Data>
                            </ds:KeyInfo>
                            <ds:Object>
                                <xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades='http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#' Target='signature'>
                                    <xades:SignedProperties Id='xadesSignedProperties'>
                                        <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                            <xades:SigningTime>2022-09-15T01:45:47Z</xades:SigningTime>
                                            <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                                <xades:Cert>
                                                    <xades:CertDigest>
                                                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256'/>
                                                        <ds:DigestValue>YTJkM2JhYTcwZTBhZTAxOGYwODMyNzY3NTdkZDM3YzhjY2IxOTIyZDZhM2RlZGJiMGY0NDUzZWJhYWI4MDhmYg==</ds:DigestValue>
                                                    </xades:CertDigest>
                                                    <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                        <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=TSZEINVOICE-SubCA-1, DC=extgazt, DC=gov, DC=local</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                                        <ds:X509SerialNumber>2475382886904809774818644480820936050208702411</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                                    </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                </xades:Cert>
                                            </xades:SigningCertificate>
                                        </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                    </xades:SignedProperties>
                                </xades:QualifyingProperties>
                            </ds:Object>
                        </ds:Signature>
                    </sac:SignatureInformation>
                </sig:UBLDocumentSignatures>
            </ext:ExtensionContent>
        </ext:UBLExtension>
    </ext:UBLExtensions>    
    <cbc:ProfileID>reporting:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
    <cbc:ID>SME00023</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:UUID>1a6db6ab-f65c-4b12-8686-53150d11e1c3</cbc:UUID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2022-09-07</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:IssueTime>12:21:28</cbc:IssueTime>
    <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode name='0100000'>388</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
    <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
    <cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>ICV</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:UUID>23</cbc:UUID>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>PIH</cbc:ID>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode='text/plain'>NWZlY2ViNjZmZmM4NmYzOGQ5NTI3ODZjNmQ2OTZjNzljMmRiYzIzOWRkNGU5MWI0NjcyOWQ3M2EyN2ZiNTdlOQ==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>


    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>QR</cbc:ID>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode='text/plain'>ARNBY21lIFdpZGdldOKAmXMgTFREAg8zMTExMTExMTExMDExMTMDFDIwMjItMDktMDdUMTI6MjE6MjhaBAQ0LjYwBQMwLjYGLFdDN2UrYkJRUW9rOUZPclMyeStCQVl0blc5QjVmdnh0RFhnSlU2dmh4NU09B2BNRVVDSVFDQ0dMN0FKYWNWT2JzN2x1RllUYnNxS3I5cUxaWCtMWWpaaXZPakRObmFZZ0lnVDBTclpaS2szTDhmelY4L0o3aDlwN3dIMEJvcXBsVzBSQmNXT1ZOZVcwdz0IWDBWMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAKA0IABDU0Drtdd/V1WZduMMS8tToBCEU9qCJU2vgyhwyjnqMxvUEoy/EsXPjv/8tre8qQaiyXuxw0RkEyL4IsMCrx2+4=</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cac:Signature>
      <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:SignatureMethod>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</cbc:SignatureMethod>
    </cac:Signature><cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:Party>
        <cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cbc:ID schemeID='CRN'></cbc:ID>
        </cac:PartyIdentification>
        <cac:PostalAddress>
            <cbc:StreetName>الامير سلطان</cbc:StreetName>
            <cbc:BuildingNumber>2322</cbc:BuildingNumber>
            <cbc:PlotIdentification>2223</cbc:PlotIdentification>
            <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>الرياض</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
            <cbc:CityName>الرياض | Riyadh</cbc:CityName>
            <cbc:PostalZone>23333</cbc:PostalZone>
            <cac:Country>
                <cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
            </cac:Country>
        </cac:PostalAddress>
        <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                <cbc:CompanyID>311111111101113</cbc:CompanyID>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
        <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
            <cbc:RegistrationName>Acme Widget’s LTD</cbc:RegistrationName>
        </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
    </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID='NAT'>311111111111113</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
                <cbc:StreetName>الرياض</cbc:StreetName>
                <cbc:BuildingNumber>1111</cbc:BuildingNumber>
                <cbc:PlotIdentification>2223</cbc:PlotIdentification>
                <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>الرياض</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
                <cbc:CityName>الدمام | Dammam</cbc:CityName>
                <cbc:PostalZone>12222</cbc:PostalZone>

                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
            <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cbc:RegistrationName>Acme Widget’s LTD 2</cbc:RegistrationName>
            </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:Delivery>
        <cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>2022-09-07</cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>
    </cac:Delivery>
    <cac:PaymentMeans>
        <cbc:PaymentMeansCode>10</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
    </cac:PaymentMeans>
    <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID='SAR'>0.00</cbc:Amount>
        <cac:TaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID schemeID='UN/ECE 5305' schemeAgencyID='6'>S</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>15</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID schemeID='UN/ECE 5153' schemeAgencyID='6'>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:TaxCategory>
    </cac:AllowanceCharge>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID='SAR'>0.6</cbc:TaxAmount>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID='SAR'>0.6</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID='SAR'>4.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID='SAR'>0.60</cbc:TaxAmount>
             <cac:TaxCategory>
                 <cbc:ID schemeID='UN/ECE 5305' schemeAgencyID='6'>S</cbc:ID>
                 <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                   <cbc:ID schemeID='UN/ECE 5153' schemeAgencyID='6'>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
             </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID='SAR'>4.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID='SAR'>4.00</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID='SAR'>4.60</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount currencyID='SAR'>0.00</cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount>
        <cbc:PrepaidAmount currencyID='SAR'>0.00</cbc:PrepaidAmount>
        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID='SAR'>4.60</cbc:PayableAmount>
    </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode='PCE'>2.000000</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID='SAR'>4.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
             <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID='SAR'>0.60</cbc:TaxAmount>
             <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID='SAR'>4.60</cbc:RoundingAmount>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>قلم رصاص</cbc:Name>
            <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
                <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID='SAR'>2.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
            <cac:AllowanceCharge>
               <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
               <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
               <cbc:Amount currencyID='SAR'>0.00</cbc:Amount>
            </cac:AllowanceCharge>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

In this xml I would like to change value of DigestValue in

```
<ds:Reference Type='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties' URI='#xadesSignedProperties'>
 <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256'/> 
 <ds:DigestValue>ZjU2ZjM4YTExODRmNzE0ZjIxODA4MDYxYjhiMzdmM2JlMTJiNWQ0N2E2YjhjNzQwMjg2NDBkMzJlM2MxNjM2Nw==</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
```

I am very beginner in xml, tried many different ways but not successful. Is it possible to add any ID field to that particular element and update it with ID. Or any other method which helps to solve this.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640395/10024425

Comment: I tried this before but it's showing error as below `Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.` Tried removing xml version element but still the same error. XML path I used is `/Invoice/ext:UBLExtensions/ext:UBLExtension/ext:ExtensionContent/sig:UBLDocumentSignatures/sac:SignatureInformation/ds:Signature/ds:SignedInfo/ds:Reference/ds:DigestValue` @Filburt

Comment: Tried your resolution @user246821 but there is error `Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.` XML Path I used is: `/Invoice/ext:UBLExtensions/ext:UBLExtension/ext:ExtensionContent/sig:UBLDocumentSignatures/sac:SignatureInformation/ds:Signature/ds:SignedInfo/ds:Reference/ds:DigestValue`

Comment: Please [edit] and post your code.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75315612/10024425

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is using LINQ to XML API that is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

> update a specific value of xml with c#

It is done in one single statement where last method is `.SetValue()` that does the job.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string FILENAME = @"e:\Temp\CodinozTechnologies.xml";
    const string NEWFILENAME = @"e:\Temp\CodinozTechnologies_New.xml";
    const string ORIGINALVALUE = "ZjU2ZjM4YTExODRmNzE0ZjIxODA4MDYxYjhiMzdmM2JlMTJiNWQ0N2E2YjhjNzQwMjg2NDBkMzJlM2MxNjM2Nw==";
    const string NEWVALUE = "++NewValue++";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
    XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#";

    xdoc.Descendants(ns + "DigestValue")
        .Where(x => x.Value == ORIGINALVALUE)
        .FirstOrDefault()?
        .SetValue(NEWVALUE);
    
    xdoc.Save(NEWFILENAME);
}
```

Comment: this works fine for me..

Comment: With your method, can you please guide me to get value of 'QR' EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject data inside '<cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>'. There are multiple '<cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>', from that I want value of QR only.

Comment: Please ask a brand new question.

Comment: Is it neccessary, it's getting duplicated. If possible just comment, it will be very helpful. I am in a hurry..

Comment: I created a new question with the requirement. Please go through it

Answer (score 0):

Use a powershell script

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$outputFilename = 'c:\temp\test1.xml'

$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$descendants = $xDoc.Descendants()

$signedInfo = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($descendants,  [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) $x[0].Name.LocalName -eq 'SignedInfo'})
$dsNs = $signedInfo.GetNamespaceOfPrefix('ds')

$references = $xDoc.Descendants($dsNs + 'Reference')
$signedReference = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($descendants,  [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) $x[0].Attribute('URI').value -eq '#xadesSignedProperties'})

$digestValue = $signedReference.Element($dsNs + 'DigestValue')
$digestValue.SetValue('ZjU2ZjM4YTExODRmNzE0ZjIxODA4MDYxYjhiMzdmM2JlMTJiNWQ0N2E2YjhjNzQwMjg2NDBkMzJlM2MxNjM2Nw==')

$xDoc.Save($outputFilename)
```