# How to retrieve a value from an xml into label?

Tags: vb.net

I have an xml like the following.

```
<Manifest Type="File">
<FilesList>
    <FileItem>
        <Version>v1.0</Version>
```

When the exe is opened, how do I get the value in  and overwrite the label?
Btw, I need to use "StartupPath" to show the xml directory.

To be simpler, I want it to be exactly like this picture, but using xml. (just a random image)
https://support.kaspersky.com/images/home_ksmac_8421_02_en13-145521.jpg

Comment: Is that the entire xml file? i.e. are all those nodes closed after that or do you have a different root (other than Manifest), and multiple FileItem, etc.?

Comment: not the entire xml, just the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XML serialization to read XML files in .NET

Make some classes for the XML file model

```
Public Class Manifest
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement>
    Public Property FilesList As FilesList
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute>
    Public Property [Type] As String
End Class

Public Class FilesList
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement>
    Public Property FileItem As FileItem
End Class

Public Class FileItem
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement>
    Public Property Version As String
End Class
```

and load the file like this

```
Dim s As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(Manifest))
Dim m As Manifest
Using sr = New System.IO.StreamReader("XmlFile1.xml")
    m = DirectCast(s.Deserialize(sr), Manifest)
End Using
Dim labelText = m.FilesList.FileItem.Version
```

Note: I asked about the XML file in a comment, and you said that's just the beginning. So the model above assumes that the complete file looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Manifest Type="File">
  <FilesList>
    <FileItem>
      <Version>v1.0</Version>
    </FileItem>
  </FilesList>
</Manifest>
```

and if it's not you need to adjust the model i.e. make things arrays when there's more than one (FileItem for example) and access it appropriately so `m.FilesList.FileItem.Version` would need to change.

Comment: Here is the entire xml https://pastebin.com/Zz9rHZ7x
Sorry, I should have shared this first :/

Comment: You just taught me how to serialize/deserialize XML attributes! Thanks! (I haven't studied XML serialization that much, please don't hate ;))

Comment: @mvydvyspy : Ouch, that was a large XML. It'd be better to read that to a string and just [get a single value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5623107) instead.

Comment: I changed the values (according to original xml) and try but label text did not change

Comment: thanks for help @djv, with few changes label it worked
label1Text = m.FilesList.FileItem.Version
deleted Dim here